# UEFI - How to send HTTP requests

Tags: uefi

I want to send HTTP request after calling `ExitBootServices()` in UEFI environment. Maybe I need to start the operating system waiting for networking, so I wrote a DXE_RUNTIME_DRIVER, but I do not know how to send HTTP requests. Does anybody know how to do that?

Comment: I am not entirely sure but aren't all drivers unloaded after the call to `ExitBootSerivices()`?

Comment: The lifecycle of DXE_RUNTIME_DRIVER is accompanied by the OS